# Adding buttons to an ImageView

Tags: android

In my app I have an ImageView that is filled in by Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/logo.png").into(imageView);
```

This works fine.  However, I would like to add a button to the top corner of each ImageView.  Obviously, this means making my own reusable instance of some kind.

I'm confused as to the best way to approach it.  Ideally I would like to create a subclass of ImageView to preserve the above syntax and semantics.  ("This is an ImageView *plus a bit.*") However, the XML required to make this sort of structure requires a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout as its root, and I can't point that at an ImageView subclass.

How could I effectively create such a subclass?

Comment: You want the imageview to be clickable or add a new button there?

Comment: Add a new button. The AOSP Dialer's speed dial "..." menus give the general idea.

Comment: Incidentally, the imageview will also be clickable but I know how to implement that.

Comment: Actually you can't subclass ImageView to add another view in it because ImageView is a subclass of View not ViewGroup, you need to subclass a ViewGroup (For example RelativeLayout or FrameLayout)

Comment: Try make you custom ImageView class which extend FrameLayout and try to add ImageView and Button to FrameLayout.

Comment: So the best I could do would be to have a custom ViewGroup subclass with a .getImageView method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since ImageView is not a viewgroup you cant add a button into a subclass of imageview.

I would solve this by instead creating a view which would be a subclass of a viewgroup ex. Frame/Realtive/etc-Layout.

It would contain the ImageView and Button, and a method
getImageView().

Then your picasso call would be:
Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/logo.png").into(mCustomView.getImageView());

---Edit---

OK Since I was on my mobile writing i could not give an example. 
This would give you a reuseable view, that also can be inflated programmatically.
You will have to create an XML layout file to be inflated by your custom class.

```
public class MyCustomImageView extends FrameLayout {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Button mButton;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyCustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_imageview, this);
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_imgv);
        mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b_btn);

        //mImageView.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){...} );
        //mButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){...} );
    }

    //Return image view for image loading etc.
    public ImageView getImageView(){
        return this.mImageView;
    }

    //Add onClickListener for the button
    public void setButtonOnClickListener(inListener){
        mButton.setOnClickListener(inListener);
    }

    //If you want you can simulate this to be an image view
    // Ex..
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable){
        iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

This can be inflated from XML layouts;

```
    <com.example.packagename.customview.MyCustomImageView  ... />
```

Or programmatically;

```
    MyCustomImageView customview = new MyCustomImageView(context);
    custom.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    custom.setButtonOnclickListener(new OnClickListener(){...});
```